# How do you check if your signing identity is installed on another Mac? (Error: Your Account already has a valid iOS Distribution Certificate)

Tags: xcode8, code-signing, testflight, apple-developer

I have an error when trying to upload an app to `TestFlight`. It says I have a valid `iOS` certificate on developer website but that it is not installed locally

[image: error message]

I did get a new MacBook recently and I think this might be causing my issue. How do I check if my singing identity is installed on another Mac and if so, how to I install it locally on my new MacBook?

Really lost here at the mo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here  are the Steps for solving this issue :

1. Go to Xcode Prefrence and Remove all developer account
2. Clean And Build ( in Simulator ) and Restart Xcode .
3. Go To Apple Developer Account ( developer.apple.com)
4. Download Certificate , provisioning profile already created
5. After Downloading , click each one to add in Keychain
6. Now Again Go To XCode Preference -> Account and Add Apple Account
7. After Adding Apple Account , There is a button to Check **View
   Details**
8. Go To view Details and just make sure everything is correct
9. Now Go to XCode and Set Automatically Managing Signing 
   10.And Run app on Device , if successful then Archive and Enjoy.

This way recently i solved one my friend issue and Hope it works for you also.

Feel free to comment . Thanks

Comment: Is this "signing identity" referring to something attached just to this application or something else? not sure what it even means

Comment: you are missing developer profile , go through this steps and it will solve your issue

Comment: It worked :) Just magic I guess.. thank you for your help. I really need to understand how this all works.

Comment: Its not a magic , to understand it you need to Follow Apple Doc , superb doc about this topic